# Fill barChartData in Stacked Bar for a json- Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js

Simply I am having one Json like

```html
[
    {
        "BugStatus": "Closed",
        "BugsSeverities": [
            {
                "Severity": "Blocking",
                "Count": 2
            },
            {
                "Severity": "Major Inconvenience",
                "Count": 3
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "BugStatus": "Needs Verification",
        "BugsSeverities": [
            {
                "Severity": "Blocking",
                "Count": 1
            },
            {
                "Severity": "Major Inconvenience",
                "Count": 1
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to show these results on a stacked bar where x-axis labels should be with BugStatus name and y-axis bar should consist of the total count present in BugsSeverities.The bar should be a combination of each BugSeverities Count i.e (2+3) for a **closed** label.
I used chart.js to implement bar chart and iam unable to implement stacked bar.
I want to use this code to implement stacked bar but Iam unable to fill **'barChartData'**

```
 <div style="display: block" *ngIf="barChartData.length > 0" class="canvas">
      <canvas baseChart
              [title]="title"
              [datasets] = "barChartData"
              [labels]="barChartLabels"
              [options]="barChartOptions"
              [legend]="barChartLegend"
              [chartType]="barChartType"
              (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
              (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"></canvas>
    </div>
```

Suggestion needed to fill ***barChartData***...... :)

Comment: any suggestions?

Comment: ant suggestions?

Comment: any suggestions